# Why CPU Usage increases rapidly when video is paused in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, video

I am working on a video app in which I have to edit video and add a layer in it and re-record the video with the layer in it.So when I run the app in iPhone and pause the video the CPU usage increases automatically from about **40% to 80%**.So if I leave it for couple of minutes in paused state then the battery gets `discharged at a rapid rate` and iPhone gets `hot`.

I don't have much knowledge about the CPU usage.Can anybody please suggest me whats wrong with the app and also suggest me some good tutorials for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Imran i also face this Problem in my same app like you ..... Just do one thing only . Write your some methods ...Like this

```
    -(void)abc{
          @autoreleasepool
              {

               //your code  
              }
            }
```

Comment: No effect dude.Is there any other thing that I can try?